# Translate cURL POST into R using the curl package

Tags: r, curl

I want to translate the following bash cURL command into R **using the curl package**. (see https://api.originstamp.com/swagger/swagger-ui.html#/proof/getProof for the background)

```
 curl -X POST "https://api.originstamp.com/v3/timestamp/proof/url" -H "accept: application/json" -H "Authorization: xxx-xxx-xxx-xxx-xxxx" -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d "{ \"currency\": 0, \"hash_string\": \"2c5d36be542f8f0e7345d77753a5d7ea61a443ba6a9a86bb060332ad56dba38e\", \"proof_type\": 1}"
```

I understand, I have to use some=how the form_data command - but I struggle with the body.

I have so far the following

```
  url <- paste(url, "timestamp", "proof", "url", sep = "/")
  url <- gsub("//", "/", url)
  url <- gsub(":/", "://", url)

  h <- curl::new_handle()

  curl::handle_setheaders(
    h,
    accept = " application/json",
    Authorization = key,
    "content-type" = "application/json"
  )

 ## Here the body needs to come in somewhere

  response <- curl::curl_fetch_memory( url, h )
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few examples in the [curl vignette](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/curl/vignettes/intro.html#performing_the_request). In particular you want to look at the `copypostfields` option:

```r
h <- new_handle()
handle_setopt(h, copypostfields = "moo=moomooo");
handle_setheaders(h,
  "Content-Type" = "text/moo",
  "Cache-Control" = "no-cache",
  "User-Agent" = "A cow"
)
req <- curl_fetch_memory("https://eu.httpbin.org/post", handle = h)
```

Note that the httr package might make this even easier with the POST() function.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Works perfectly. I was using the http package, which is indeed easier to use, but I want to cut down on dependencies - which I can do now.